# Do Virginia Democrats support the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, electoral-college, na-po-vo-inter-co, virginia

Virginia is not currently a member of the [National Popular Vote Interstate Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Popular_Vote_Interstate_Compact). The NPVIC is very popular with Democratic voters (a [2018 Pew Research Center Poll](https://www.people-press.org/2018/04/26/5-the-electoral-college-congress-and-representation/) showed 75% of Democrats support eliminating the Electoral College) and with Democrats taking full control of Virginia state government, they potentially have the opportunity to implement it in a new state.

[image]

Has the Virginia Democratic party stated whether they plan to adopt the NPVIC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[nationalpopularvote.com](https://www.nationalpopularvote.com/state/va) is a good resource for this. This year a bill was introduced by three Virginia delegates [HB 2422](http://lis.virginia.gov/cgi-bin/legp604.exe?191+sum+HB2422), but it was [defeated in Privileges and Elections subcommittee](https://ballot-access.org/2019/02/08/national-popular-vote-bill-defeated-in-virginia-legislative-committee/) in February.

Last year two of the same delegates (Mark Levine and Marcus Simon, both Democrats) introduced a similar bill, [HB 99](http://lis.virginia.gov/cgi-bin/legp604.exe?181+sum+HB99), that was also defeated in the same subcomittee the next month.

In 2017 the current Governor of Virginia, Democrat Ralph Northam, wrote a post on [Medium](https://medium.com/@RalphNortham/virginia-votes-c29cd5c9da11) where he explicitly supports the idea:

> Finally, Ralph will support Virginia signing the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact to award all the commonwealth’s electoral votes to whichever presidential candidate wins the overall popular vote in the 50 states and the District of Columbia.

Comment: Nice answer! Also relevant was that the vote on HB99 was along party lines (4R opposed, 2D in favor).